# Can I determine which regex in an either or statement matches my string?

Tags: regex, perl

For this statement:

```
if ($SDescription =~ m/$sdescription_1/gi or $SDescription =~ m/$sdescription_2/gi){
#...
}
```

Besides printing `$SDescription` to compare it manually, is it possible to tell which `$SDescription` matched: `$sdescription_1` or `$sdescription_2`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In scalar context, the `=~` operator returns the number of matches. Without the `/g` modifier, the number of matches is either 0 or 1, so you could do something like

```
$match_val = ($SDescription =~ m/$sdescription_1/i)
         + 2 * ($SDescription =~ m/$sdescription_2/i);
if ($match_val) {

    if ($match_val == 1) { ... }  # matched first regex
    if ($match_val == 2) { ... }  # matched second regex
    if ($match_val == 3) { ... }  # matched both regex

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Is there a reason why you don't want to write something like this? (The `/g` modifier is superflous unless you are using the `\G` anchor in a later match: a pattern either matches or it doesn't.)

```
if ($SDescription =~ /$sdescription_1/i) {
  # Do stuff for first pattern
}
elsif ($SDescription =~ /$sdescription_2/i) {
  # Do stuff for second pattern
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Non-Matching Groups (?:) to accomplish this.  For your code I'd try something like this:

```
if ($SDescription =~ m/((?:$sdescription_1))|((?:$sdescription_2))/gi) {

# $1 will hold a value IFF $sdescription_1 matches
# $2 will hold a value IFF $sdescription_2 matches

}
```

Which ever "string" or pattern matched should show up in either $1 or $2.  See test program below:

Test Program:

```
$str1 = "TEST1";
$str2 = "TEST2";

#Match results on $str1 (group 1)
$str1 =~ /((?:TEST1))|((?:TEST2))/;
print "[$1] [$2]\n";

#Match results on $str2 (group 2)
$str2 =~ /((?:TEST1))|((?:TEST2))/;    
print "[$1] [$2]\n";
```

returns the results:

```
[TEST1] []
[] [TEST2]
```

Comment: You don't need the non-capturing groups here. Putting them inside ( ) is redundant. The code works but no need to bring (?: ) into the picture.

Comment: - I believe if the regex is a little more complicated than just TEST1 non-matching groups could be useful... no?

Comment: Maybe, but they have nothing at all to do with this problem or with your solution. They are unnecessary and confuse the issue. ((?:x)) is precisely equivalent to (x) even if x is a complex expression.